# How to make changes in calendar title?

Tags: views, datetime

[image]

I have created a calendar with calendar module used in views.
Here I would like to make change from "Wednesday, October 1, 2014" to "October, 2014" (red color).

Comment: Did you try to solve this yourself? What is the issue you are running into?

Comment: i got the answer on https://www.drupal.org/node/2315511